# Help to understand these two sentences.

Tags: sentence-meaning

I bumped into this post from a website, where person A posted a sentence and B responsed to it. I totally can not understand what those sentences mean here.

> A: Give enough rope to the bumbling Orange Fart-in-Chief, then sit back and enjoy the latest reality TV show.
>
> B: kayturd take your libturd a s and go jump off a cliff turd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is making reference to an idiom in English, "give him enough rope to hang himself."  Meaning, allow someone enough freedom, and eventually they will, of their own volition, do something to embarrass themselves.  If you have someone under your authority that you don't trust, you can micromanage them to make sure they don't do something foolish, or you can allow them to act independently, confident that they will mess up in a way that is clearly their fault, not yours.

"Orange Fart-In-Chief" is a reference to US President Donald Trump.  "Commander-In-Chief" is one of the titles of the President, referring to the position of head of the US military.  Using Fart instead of Commander is just replacing a respectful term for an insulting one.  "Orange" is a derogatory reference specifically to Trump, calling out the peculiar color of his skin as a result of "fake tanning".

Reality TV shows are renowned for the overly dramatic personal dynamics, infighting and double-crossing, and schadenfreude - we watch because we enjoy viewing the suffering of other people.

So, A is saying, "Don't try to resist the policies of President Trump that you philosophically oppose - given unchecked power he will eventually do something so foolish that condemnation of him will become a spectator sport."

B is a supporter of Trump, and is responding to A's statement by scatological name-calling.

"Kayturd" might be a play on A's screen name, or it might be short for "Okay, you shit."  (Turd is a less offensive version of shit)

The left wing in the US are frequently referred to as liberals.  The right has recently taken to calling them the insulting term "libtard" meaning, only a mentally retarded person would be a liberal.  B has changed this term to "libturd", meaning only a shitty person would be a liberal.

"Take your libturd a s" is just a censored "take your liberal ass"

"Go jump off a cliff" is a dismissive way of telling someone you do not value their expressed opinion - you wish they would leave in the most uncomfortable way possible.  I think he means to say "go jump off a cliff, turd" but forgot the comma.

So, long translation:

A: "Don't try to resist the policies of President Trump that you philosophically oppose - given unchecked power he will eventually do something so foolish that condemnation of him will become a spectator sport."

B: "Anyone expressing criticism of the president must be a liberal, and therefore a shitty person.  Your opinion is not welcome - you should go away."

or, in brief:

A: "I don't like Trump, but he will mess up soon enough without my opposition."

B "If you don't like Donald Trump, you can fuck off."

Comment: It's very complicated to me. I need take some time to digest.

Comment: It is mixing slang, idiom, and implied understanding of politics.  This is very high level for a non-native speaker.

Comment: I am curious if natives could understand it easily when they heard for the first time?

Comment: "go jump off a cliff" and "enough rope to hang himself" are idiomatic expressions that would be familiar to most native speakers of English, although the second is less common and of an older generation.  All of the rest of it - orange, fart-in-chief, libturd - would be recognized by anyone who follows uncivil discourse about politics.  No one of these pieces is difficult, but it did take me a while to figure out the whole thing because there are so many pieces.  I expect it would be similar for most natives.